# How to duplicate queryset output

Tags: django, django-queryset

When the test row satisfies both conditions 1 and 2, is there a way to print the query set twice? I've searched a lot about solutions, but only the method to distinct() duplicate querysets is shown, and there is no way to print duplicate querysets more than once.

```
condition_1 = Student.objects.filter(Q(register_date__gte=from_date) & Q(register_date__lte=to_date))

condition_2 = Student.objects.filter(Q(eating_date__gte=from_date) & Q(eating_date__lte=to_date))

gap = ETC.objects.filter(Q(id__in=condition_1)) | Q(id__in=gap_condition_2))\
        .annotate(total_gap=('create_date', filter=Q(id__in=condition_1.values('id')) +
                             'create_date', filter=Q(id__in=condition_2.values('id')))
```

Comment: Can you give example data and inputs and then expected outputs? You have two models but they both seem to be filtered by the same ids?

Comment: Iain Shelvington <QuerySet [{'id': 24, 'register_date': datetime.date(2021, 9, 14), 'eating_date': datetime.date(2021, 9, 11), 'total_gap': 3}]> 
Both register date and eating date items satisfy the condition. There is one queryset that is output, but I want two to be output. '|' I tried to merge with , but the primary key is automatically recognized, so this method is also output as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [union](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#union) to combine the results of two querysets, pass `all=True` to allow duplicates

```
all_students = condition_1.union(condition_2, all=True)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for solving the problem I have. Another problem arose. How do I change my code to union querysets with different field names? Everything else is the same, each is different for only one field.

Comment: Both querysets must have the same fields. What are the fields? Could you add a default/null value for them?

Comment: <QuerySet [{'id': 24, 'register_date': datetime.date(2021, 9, 14), 'eating_date': datetime.date(2021, 9, 11), 'total_gap': 3}]>
<QuerySet [{'id': 24, 'register_date': datetime.date(2021, 9, 14), 'eating_date': datetime.date(2021, 9, 11), 'CDCD_gap': 1}]>    A new variable is created through annotate and stored in values() to be output to the template.

Comment: Could you annotate each queryset with the field it's missing with a null/None/0 value?

Comment: QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s): None.      I may have misunderstood what you said. The error is: Thanks for your help.

Comment: `.annotate(total_gap=Value(None))` - `from django.db.models import Value`. Or try some other value like 0